# How to grant database privileges in DB2 to other Domain users

Tags: java, db2

In a Java application, I have created 2 databases in DB2 with administrative authorities. Now using an application, want to access same databases over LAN but need to grant database privileges to other (in same Domain) Domain users, so that they can access the same databases as a end users.

I have tried DB2 GRANT command, but it doesn't allow others to access those database, But if they use same user/pwd as of Administrator, DB2 allow them to access databases. But it may be security issue to know the Administrator user/pwd.

Is there any way to do this on command prompt i.e. db2cmd

```
GRANT CONNECT,ACCESSCTRL,DATAACCESS,DBADM,SECADM ON DATABASE TO USER Kishore
```

This command doesn't solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

I did as @Ian Bjorhovde suggested. Now the DB2 services are running as Domain\Admin and GRANT command is successfully executed but still other Domain users are not able to connect to DBs (with their own authentications) which are created by Admin. This code is used

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://SERVERNAME:50000/TESTDB", UserName, PassWord);
```

The connection is created but throws SQL exception (SQLCODE=-204) while firing any SELECT query even on supplied the UserName as Domain\UserName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To authenticate against the domain, the DB2 Service (instance) must be running using a domain account - it can't be started using an account defined on the local machine.  You can stop your instance and then from the Windows Services panel change the DB2 service to start using a domain ID.

Make sure that this domain ID has sufficient privileges, as [documented here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0007134.html).

Comment: Thanks @Ian. Yes DB2 services are running using a local account on my machine.  If I start them as domain account then how to grant access to others then?

Comment: As soon as the instance is running using a domain ID, then it will be able to authenticate users against the domain.  You have already issued the GRANT statement, so you should be all set.